# Is there a way for me to make my python discord bot do something at a certain time

Tags: python, datetime, flask, discord.py, replit

So I need to know how to make my python discord bot do something at a certain time because I want it to clear all messages in a channel at around 5:00am when no one is on I will be using the date time module but the problem is I do not want it to interfere with the rest of my bot is there any way I can do this. I know that there are other threads about this but none of them bring up the part about interference with the rest of there bot. And I am using repl.it to run the bot in case that is needed to be known.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your code, and what you have tried already. It would also help to explain what you mean by "interfering". Importing a module in python doesn't normally interfere with existing code, unless you change the existing code.

Comment: i have not tried anything because the only way I can think of would be a while loop which would interfere with my code already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an asynchronous [background task](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py). During bot startup, calculate how many seconds are left to 5 AM and then sleep the task until then.

There is no reason that it should "interfere" with the rest of your code. I assume that you tried using [blocking functions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean) such as `time.sleep()`. You can use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.

Comment: and I need it to go off at 5 am which means I cannot use a time.sleep I need something more like if datetime = 5am how would I do that with asyncio

Comment: You can use ```asyncio.sleep()```. 

Simply calculate how many seconds there are to 5 AM when the bot starts up.

You don't need to constantly check if datetime == 5 am.

Comment: Lucy I was having trouble writing the code could you give me a code sample of what the complete code would look like